# Is there a component to show an embeded swf (flash file) stored as a Resource in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Can anyone recommend the best component to show an embedded flash movie (swf file) stored as a Resource in my Delphi executable?

i want to read a play a .swf file in resource with Transparecy in delphi Xe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your options:

1. [Flash Viewer Engine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227032247/http://www.delphiflash.com/flash-viewer-engine)
2. [F-In-Box](https://www.f-in-box.com/)
3. [KSDev Flash Engine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100118043554/https://www.ksdev.com/flashengine/index.html)

I personally recommend *Flash Viewer Engine* (first) because I use their Delphi SWF SDK too and it also supports Delphi XE very well.